# Java OS Questions

Tags: java, assembly, operating-system, jvm

Okay, Ive been looking into Assembly language.
I already know how to program in java.
I read online that it is possible to write an OS in Java if you can provide enough
assembly code to support a Java Virtual Machine.
Does anyone know what a Java Virtual Machine requires from a kernel/assembly bin files?
And how do you invoke a JVM from assembly code / start a JVM with a predefined class?

Comment: There is a minimum you can provide. But for advanced features such as Java NIO, networking etc. you might want to provide as much as a regular operating system does.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you mean something like [JNode](http://www.jnode.org/)? It's an complete operating sytem written in Java. It has a small micro kernel (called nano-kernel) written in Assembler and C. This Code depends on the hardware. Their also have written an Java compiler, which compiles the Java parts of the OS to native code.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: JNode is a dead project, as far as I can see.

Comment: yeah, but the last commit on gitorius is from 2011...

Comment: Imagine that, almost two years without even so much as a tiny little *commit*. If not dead, it's on life support.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assuming you already have an operating system?  If so, in terms of what you'd need to do to kick off a JVM, you would just need to make a system call to launch the JVM application and provide appropriate arguments.

If you are asking, "what code do I need to write in order to have an OS that runs itself inside the JVM?" then, to quote Carl Sagan, "you first have to invent the universe."

The Java VM provides the many features and capabilities it does because it uses those same features from the underlying system and abstracts them into the virtual machine.  Thus, the Windows JVM is built on Windows functionality, and the Linux JVM is built on Linux functionality, and so forth.  This means, in order to host your own OS inside a JVM, you would need to write bootstrapping code to host the JVM on the hardware, and then write the OS code in Java to run inside the JVM.

> "Does anyone know what a Java Virtual Machine requires from a
>   kernel/assembly bin files?"

Yes, and the answer is, whatever you want the computer to do, you'll need to write the code for.  File system support, memory management, threading--everything the hosted application would ask the JVM to do, Java is going to turn around and ask the lower level--your code, in this case--to do, so you would have to write it.

Comment: As already mentioned, you could also check out JNode.